# How to run code sequentially(line by line / single threaded) in Lua?

Tags: lua

I am having some difficulty with programming in lua. I have seen that Lua does not execute code sequentially like Python. Therefore I am an unable to update a variable to the value which it gets from a loop or an if/else statement. The value only gets updated within the if/else or loop block but after the block the variable returns its initial value or nil rathen than the updated value. I hope I made myself clear. Please help.
Here's a Code Snippet:

```
local list = {}
function refresh_applist()
    apps_gen.generate(function (applist) -- callback function
        list = applist -- assigning value to var list
        naughty.notify({text = type(list[10])}) -- Equivalent to print(type(list[10])) & Outputs 'table'
    end)
    naughty.notify({text = type(list[10])}) -- Outputs nil
end
```

Here's what apps_gen.generate do

```
function apps_gen.generate(callback)
    -- Update icons for category entries
    apps_gen.lookup_category_icons()

    local result = {}
    local unique_entries = {}
    local dirs_parsed = 0

    for _, dir in ipairs(apps_gen.all_menu_dirs) do
        utils.parse_dir(dir, function(entries)
            entries = entries or {}
            for _, entry in ipairs(entries) do
                -- Check whether to include program in the menu
                if entry.show and entry.Name and entry.cmdline then
                    local unique_key = entry.Name .. '\0' .. entry.cmdline
                    if not unique_entries[unique_key] then
                        local target_category = nil
                        -- Check if the program falls into at least one of the
                        -- usable categories. Set target_category to be the id
                        -- of the first category it finds.
                        if entry.categories then
                            for _, category in pairs(entry.categories) do
                                local cat_key, cat_use =
                                get_category_name_and_usage_by_type(category)
                                if cat_key and cat_use then
                                    target_category = cat_key
                                    break
                                end
                            end
                        end

                        local name = utils.rtrim(entry.Name) or ""
                        local cmdline = utils.rtrim(entry.cmdline) or ""
                        local icon = entry.icon_path or nil
                        table.insert(result, { name = name,
                                     cmdline = cmdline,
                                     icon = icon,
                                     category = target_category })
                        unique_entries[unique_key] = true
                    end
                end
            end
            dirs_parsed = dirs_parsed + 1
            if dirs_parsed == #apps_gen.all_menu_dirs then
                callback(result)
            end
        end)
    end
end
```

Comment: I don't see any for loop or if statement in your code. please provide the code that is causing the problems. Of course Lua executes code sequentially. if a variable "looses its value after a block" it's usually because of wrong scoping.  what is `applist[10]`?

Comment: and what is `applist` outside of your callback's scope? where do you define it?

Comment: Lua *does* execute code sequentially, as long as it runs in a single thread (which it normally does)

Comment: @Piglet I hope the additional code has answered your question. Btw, applist is a table so applist[10] is printing the type of 10th value in the table. Outside of callback applist has no scope because the callback created it.

Comment: If `applist` only exists inside the callback, how are you indexing it outside the callback without getting an error message?

Comment: Typo, I am extremely sorry. Check again

Comment: Ok, that makes a bit more sense. We still don't know what `naughty.notify` is doing. Could it be doing something strange that you haven't thought of?

Comment: Also, you might need to check out [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will be difficult for us to help without some version of the code that we can run ourselves.

Comment: how can you fix a typo like that and still have the same behaviour? that doesn't make sense. didn't you copy your actual code?

Comment: The typo was in the question. I keep trying to find the cause in the main code and so I copied the wrong code.

Comment: What enforces that you have at least `10` results in `result`? what is special about `10`? do you have this issue when you check `1` through `9`?

Comment: 10 is completely random but I am sure it has 21 values at least and yes it happens through 1 - 9 too.

Comment: is `callback(result)` the last time you reference `result`? are `list` or `result` are altered in `utils.parse_dir`? I can only "recreate" your issue if i add additional code to what you provided.

Comment: Thanks @Nifim ! That solved. I used utils.parse_dir(x,y) without actually knowing how it works or even skimming through it. It uses an asynchoronous code to do several things which made the delay in output. Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 2):

> How to run code sequentially(line by line / single threaded) in Lua?

Lua scripts are interpeted line by line and hence sequentially. There is nothing you have to do to accomplish that.

create a local table `list`

```
local list = {}
```

create a global function `refresh_applist` with no arguments

```
    function refresh_applist()
        apps_gen.generate(function (applist)
            list = applist
            naughty.notify({text = type(applist[10])})
        end)
        naughty.notify({text = type(applist[10])}) -- Outputs nil
    end
```

If you later call `refresh_applist`, it will call a function `apps_gen.generate` with an anonymous function as it's only parameter.

Then it calls `naughty.notify({text = type(applist[10])})` which will probably output the type of `applist[10]` somewhere. In the provided code applist does not exist. As you don't mention a script error it is most likely a table value, otherwise you wouldn't be allowed to index it and hence it wouldn't output nil.

If the anonymous function was ever to be called, it would assign its argument `applist` to its upvalue `list` and also call `naughty.notify({text = type(applist[10])})`. But this time `applist` is its local argument, not that unknown value from above.

### Response to your comments and edit, adding more code:

> I am unable to use the table 'applist' outside of the callback
> function

That is, because (at least in the provided code) applist does not exist outside the callback function. applist is a function parameter that is local to the callback function's scope. Outside the callback it is nil unless you have another `applist` that is created earlier in the correct scope.

As tables are passed by reference, `applist` is nothing but a reference to `result` which callback is called with.

You should get a Lua error for indexing a nil value when you attempt to call `type(applist[10])` outside the callback function.

Comment: Edited the question please check again. In simple words the problem is, I am unable to use the table 'applist' outside of the callback function in main file(code 1) or outside of if/else block in apps_gen file(code 2). If the code was running line by line I should have got the table's 10th index a string and not nil considering applist has 21 values. and also if it was running sequentially I should've received the output of second 'naughty.notify' after the first 'naughty.notify' but it happened the other way 'round i.e I received output 'nil' before 'table'

Comment: I don't see `applist` defined anywhere except inside the callback. After that callback, `applist[10]` should be giving you an index error.

Comment: 'applist' was a typo, kindly check again. I already assigned applist to list to able to use later which i couldn't because callback is taking longer to execute and Lua parallely runs the code after it, before it.